# Add LimaCharlie MacOS Arm64 install file to Microsoft Intune

Tags: microsoft-intune

I want to push LimaCharlie Sensor for all my MacOS users.

**LimaCharlie gives the following instructions:**

1. Download LimaCharlie for MacOS
   https://downloads.limacharlie.io/sensor/mac/arm64
2. Open a terminal with root privileges and navigate to the directory of the downloaded installer.
3. Copy the following command and use it to run the installer:

`chmod +x lc_sensor ; sudo ./lc_sensor -i AAAABgAAAQsFAAAAI2I3NjA5M2MzNjYy...CAwEAAQ==`

**This is a screenshot of the instructions:**

[image]

I want to do this using Microsoft Intune. However the file seems like it is missing a file extension? Intune says it can deploy a Line of Business App for macOS with file extension .pkg. Is the sensor a PKG file?

I tried to just select "hcp_osx_x64_release_4.29.0" as a file in Microsoft Intune but it does not work.

[image]